# StackOverflowError is thrown by my custom bottom-sheet widget

Tags: flutter, parse-server

when I try to set values on my bottom-sheets widget, the following  error is thrown:

> Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════ The following StackOverflowError
> was thrown building BSheetWidget(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery],
> state: _BSheetWidgetState#759dc): Stack Overflow
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was BSheetWidget
> lib\…\client\clientscreen_view.dart:874 When the exception was thrown,
> this was the stack
> #0      Driver.carReference package:taxi_app/…/models/driver.dart:29
> #1      Driver.carReference package:taxi_app/…/models/driver.dart:29
> #2      Driver.carReference package:taxi_app/…/models/driver.dart:29
> #3      Driver.carReference package:taxi_app/…/models/driver.dart:29
> #4      Driver.carReference package:taxi_app/…/models/driver.dart:29 ...
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Reloaded 1 of 2190 libraries in 2 987ms.

I find that the problem is here:

```
child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text('vehicule model'),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text(widget.fullData.driver.carReference != null ? widget.fullData.driver.carReference.toString() : '', style: TextStyle(color: ThemeUtils.bluePlus,fontSize: 18)), //
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

but I find that when I tried to change the Text like :

```
 Text(widget.fullData.driver.carReference != null ? widget.fullData.driver.carReference.toString() : '', style: TextStyle(color: ThemeUtils.bluePlus,fontSize: 18)),
```

it works:

my model:

```
@override
  Driver clone(Map<String, dynamic> map) => Driver()..fromJson(map);

  static const String carNameKey = 'carName';
  static const String carReferenceKey = 'carReference';
  static const String carSerieKey = 'carSerie';
  static const String carImageKey = 'carImage';

  String get carName => get<String>(carNameKey);
  String get carReference => get<String>(carReference);
  String get carSerie => get<String>(carSerie);
  ParseFile get carImage => get<ParseFile>(carImageKey);

  set carName(String value) => set<String>(carNameKey, value);
  set carReference(String value) => set<String>(carReferenceKey, value);
  set carSerie(String value) => set<String>(carSerieKey, value);
  set carImage(ParseFile value) => set<ParseFile>(carImageKey, value);
```

Comment: i replaced `Text(widget.fullData.driver.carReference != .....` with dummy text `Container` works fine. maybe you need to check parent level of thins widget, because , it's using column, can you share it's parent

Comment: I have replaced widget.fullData.driver.carReference with  dummy text  too and it works I thnink the prb is in the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to modify my setter to be

```
  String get carReference => get<String>(carReferenceKey);
  String get carSerie => get<String>(carSerieKey);
```